# Submit 'links' with CakePHP formHelper

Tags: html, forms, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.4

Is it possible to create a submit 'link' with CakePHP 2.4's FormHelper? I'm trying to put some less-used submit buttons from my POST form into a Bootstrap dropdown and am running into trouble since they only seem to be able to create a button, which won't work in a dropdown.

Since this is inside a form already, clearly this isn't what I want a postLink for- but is there any good Cake way around this? `postLink` just makes a plain link, but it won't play well inside another form.

```
echo $this->Form->button('Download Excel CSV', array(
                    'type' => 'submit',
                    'class' => '',
                    'formaction' => '/posts/csv',
                ));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the HtmlHelper's `url()` method:

```
<button type="button" formaction="<?php echo $this->Html->url('/posts/csv'); ?>">
    Click Here
</button>
```

(I realize you don't want it in a button element, but - showing the concept).

---

Side note: you should really be using an array instead of a hard-coded formaction:

```
$this->Html->url(array('controller'=>'posts', 'action'=>'csv'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the array tip. What I was wondering was whether there were a way of making a submit *link* in the form? I could do it with JS but I'd rather stay straight-HTML if I can help it.

Comment: @schnauss - Ah, so this question really has nothing to do with CakePHP the, right?  If you're asking how to do it in CakePHP, then supply the HTML you'd like to create.

Comment: Yeah, looks like I'll have to use `url` and use JS to submit the form to the different action. Thanks!